# How to use referenced c# dll code in a VS C# console application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

So I have two dlls, `Algorithms.dll` and `Data_Structures.dll` (I made these from projects I found on GitHub). Using the browse feature I have managed to add both of the DLL files as references to my Visual Studio 2017 console project. The problem is I can't do anything else with them. Whenever I try to reference something within either file, it simply cannot be found. The only thing that is recognized is the namespace, but nothing inside of that.

What do I need to do to get VS to find the classes these DLLs contain so I can use them? I am aware I need to use `Algorithms.Sorting` for the example but I can't call *anything* so I used this as an example.

P.S. If you need more info, please ask. I'm not sure what's relevant to this issue.

EDIT: Ok, it was misleading to have that kind of example. Corrected but please read the question.

EDIT: I tried this on Monodevelop and get the same issue. Maybe it's not the IDE that's the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Algorithms.Sorting; // Error, Sorting cannot be found, and neither can the file container Sorting
using Data_Structures; //Perfectly ok, can find the namespace

namespace CS_HW2_Testing_App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // I'd like to call MergeSort and so forth here. What am I missing?!
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the top piece of the file containing MergeSort if it helps

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Algorithms.Common;

namespace Algorithms.Sorting
{
    public static class MergeSorter
    {
        //
        // Public merge-sort API
        public static List<T> MergeSort<T>(this List<T> collection, Comparer<T> comparer = null)
        {
            comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;

            return InternalMergeSort(collection, 0, collection.Count - 1, comparer);
        }
...
```

Comment: Best guess is that you are referencing an *old version* of `Algorithms.dll` that was compiled before the `MergeSorter` class was added. Try removing and adding the reference of `Algorithms.dll` that you *know* was compiled with that class in it. Also, make sure that the `Algorithms` project *actually did* compile and that it didn't spit out any compile errors.

Comment: I can't reference anything. And I just compiled it tonight and there is only one compilation. There are a few warnings but they're from items I won't be using. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: When you look at the references of the project, the reference to the dll is valid? no warning signs?

Comment: Yes, the only detectable difference from a normal reference is that 'Strong Name' is False.

Answer (score 1):

In the first code block, you're importing the wrong namespace: `using Algorithms.MergeSort` should be `using Algorithms.Sorting`. Then you can use `MergeSorter.MergeSort<T>(...)` in your code!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the namespace not the class.

```
using Algorithms.Sorting; //instead of using Algorithms.MergeSort;
```

Plus make sure the classes are public

Comment: Try building the project even if you have highlighted errors in VS. If it compiles you need to restart VS and/or clear R# cache.